# Sometimes C# XmlSerializer Serialize(save) wrong, more characters than expect

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Normally you operate the file it works well,but sometimes file goes wrong like this..(the end extra part "**ConfigSetting>**" ), what i've done is open, edit and save it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SystemConfigSetting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" IsRuntime="true">
<ReportSchedulers>
<ReportScheduler ReportName="report1" FullreportName="report1" IsEnableAutosaveReport="true" Hour="14" Minute="50" Second="0" ReportSave="Daily" DayofWeek="Sunday" LastUpdate="0001-01-01T00:00:00" />
<ReportScheduler ReportName="report2" FullreportName="report2" IsEnableAutosaveReport="false" Hour="0" Minute="0" Second="0" ReportSave="Daily" DayofWeek="Sunday" LastUpdate="0001-01-01T00:00:00" />
<ReportScheduler ReportName="report3" FullreportName="report3" IsEnableAutosaveReport="false" Hour="0" Minute="0" Second="0" ReportSave="Daily" DayofWeek="Sunday" LastUpdate="0001-01-01T00:00:00" />
<ReportScheduler ReportName="report4" FullreportName="report4" IsEnableAutosaveReport="false" Hour="0" Minute="0" Second="0" ReportSave="Daily" DayofWeek="Sunday" LastUpdate="0001-01-01T00:00:00" />
<ReportScheduler ReportName="report5" FullreportName="report5" IsEnableAutosaveReport="false" Hour="0" Minute="0" Second="0" ReportSave="Daily" DayofWeek="Sunday" LastUpdate="0001-01-01T00:00:00" />
</ReportSchedulers>
</SystemConfigSetting>ConfigSetting>
```

Other part is right except the ending **ConfigSetting>** , and i try to delete the end extra part and the config file will be able to deserializable.

Below is my code.

**Save system config:**

```
public static bool SaveSystemConfig(SystemConfigSetting systemConfig)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SystemConfigSetting));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(CONFIGFILEPATH), FileMode.Open))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, systemConfig);
                fs.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**SystemConfigSetting:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace HZSpreadSheet.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot]
    public class SystemConfigSetting
    {
        private bool isRuntime = false;
        private List<ReportScheduler> reportSchedulers = new List<ReportScheduler>();
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool IsRuntime { get => isRuntime; set => isRuntime = value; }
        [XmlArray]
        [XmlArrayItem]
        public List<ReportScheduler> ReportSchedulers { get => reportSchedulers; set => reportSchedulers = value; }
    }
}
```

**ReportScheduler:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace HZSpreadSheet.Model
{
    public enum ReportSaveFrequency
    {
        Daily = 0,
        Weekly = 1,
        Monthly = 2,
        Manually =3
    }
    public enum DayofWeek
    {
        Sunday = 0,
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday = 2,
        Wednesday = 3,
        Thursday = 4,
        Friday = 5,
        Saturday = 6
    }
    [XmlRoot]
    public class ReportScheduler
    {
        private string abbr_reportName;
        private string fullreportName;
        private bool isEnableAutosaveReport = false;
        private int hour = 0;
        private int minute = 0;
        private int second =0;
        private DateTime lastUpdate;
        private DayofWeek dayofWeek;
        private ReportSaveFrequency reportSaveFrequency;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ReportName { get => abbr_reportName; set => abbr_reportName = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string FullreportName { get => fullreportName; set => fullreportName = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool IsEnableAutosaveReport { get => isEnableAutosaveReport; set => isEnableAutosaveReport = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Hour { get => hour; set => hour = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Minute { get => minute; set => minute = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Second { get => second; set => second = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public ReportSaveFrequency ReportSaveFrequency { get => reportSaveFrequency; set => reportSaveFrequency = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public DayofWeek DayofWeek { get => dayofWeek; set => dayofWeek = value; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get => lastUpdate; set => lastUpdate = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code contains syntax error, so we can't really trust what you claim is happening.

Comment: Do a `using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(CONFIGFILEPATH), FileMode.Create))` instead of `FileMode.Open`

Comment: Ok, i'll give it try. How about OpenOrCreate? tried openorcreate before but still same.

Comment: No, [OpenOrCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.8)  would not work either as it is defined as *Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists; otherwise, a new file should be created.* and only opening the existing file is the root cause of your problem. Create is the only sensible option, assuming you might have a situation where the file doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you overwrite a file (or similar stream) and overwrite a *longer* file with *shorter* data, without truncating it. If you open an existing file for random access with write (`FileMode.Open`), it assumes you are going to edit the contents, but does *not* assume that you only want the new bits. What you're seeing is the extra bytes from the *old* payload, which are not automatically removed. There are two ways to truncate:

1. use `FileMode.Create` when opening the file, which initializes the file as zero-length
2. use `SetLength` on the `Stream` when you've finished writing, to tell it the new length - for example `stream.SetLength(stream.Position);`

Comment: Is there a specific benefit for doing option 2?

Comment: @rene not if you control the code that is creating/opening the stream, no